# Django query: Item in model who is not in other model

Tags: django, django-models, orm

Noob Django ORM question here:

I have a model similar to this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default="")

class Audited(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="logs"
    )
    city = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
```

I have been scratching my head with this problem and I can not figure out how to solve it.

Given a city, I need the company that do not have been audited on that city, so basically the Company who does not have a record on Audited with that city.

So for example, if the city is New York, and there is no record in Audited with a company like Oracle and city as New York, I receive Oracle.

It is very confusing to me because the ORM appears to have been designed for positive relations, like "the item from table A who has a record on Table B", and this is precisely the opposite.
Any clue of how can I do this?

Comment: I assume there can be *multiple* copanies?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple companies, but I always will need the first one, because after that I will add the row to Audited (for example, Oracle-New York), so the next time I asked for the next company to audit on New York, Oracle will be ignored. After the table is full (all the companies have records in New York, for example), I have to use other logic (the company audited on that city with the oldest date)

Comment: You should remove the id field from Company model as django creates one automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with [**`.exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude):

```
Company.objects.exclude(logs__city=my_city)
```

So you will retain `Company`s for which no `Audited` exists for the given *`my_city`*.